# Android Autocomplete not functioning how is supposed to..!

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I have this Autocomplete class and I am modifying the adapter so that, instead of just text, it will show an icon in front of the text that appears. All the choices available are stored in an array of strings.

Now, for some reason,  it only shows 5 items no matter what I type.

```
public class AutoCompleteText extends Activity{

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arow,parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.element);
        label.setText(listItems[position]);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

        if("Item1".equals(listItems[position])|| something else || something else){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
        }
        else if("Item2".equals(listItems[position])|| something else || something else){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
        }
        else if("Item3".equals(listItems[position])|| something else || something else){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
        }
        else if("Item4".equals(listItems[position])|| something else || something else){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.img4);
        }
        else if("Item5".equals(listItems[position])|| something else || something else){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.img5);
        }
        else if("Item6".equals(listItems[position])|| something else || something else) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.img6);
        }
        else{
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
        }
        return row;
    }
}


AutoCompleteTextView acTextView;
private static String listItems[] = { "Item1", "Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9", "Item10"
                                        "Item11", "Item12","Item13","Item14","Item15", "Item16", "Item17", "Item18", "Item19", "Item20");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    acTextView.setThreshold(1);
    acTextView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(AutoCompleteText.this,R.layout.arow, listItems));
    acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                try {
                    //random staff
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }

    );
}
```

}

the app compiles and runs fine without any errors. Can anyone help me on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't compare `String`s with `==` since that checks if it is the same Object not the same text. Use `.equals` instead.

```
if ("Item6".equals(listItems[position]) {
```

It might work in your case since the compiler might be smart enough to use the same object to represent the text but it' usually not a good idea.

Also you just have 5 (+default) items in your code. Do you see those?

Comment: Added .equals(listItems[position]) to all string checks but still, is not working. I am able to see only selected elements eg Item1,Item2, Item4, Item5. Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you see? A list of 20 items that show the wrong icons or text or only a list of 5 items?

Comment: I see the first 7 elements of the array. Their icons are correct. I use this custom adapter class inside other classes and it works fine...

Comment: maybe a layout issue then, e.g. not enough [dropDownHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:dropDownHeight)?

Comment: no because no matter what I enter in the autocomplete, it will show me those values.. I don't get it.. If i do ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter); it WORKS FINE!! but if i modify the adapter then its not working

Comment: if you enter "Item2" you should imo see "Item2" and "Item20", is that true?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10136/discussion-between-iced-earth-and-zapl)

Comment: yes I get all the possible values if i use the normal adapter, but if i use mine i dont for some reason